# How to store thirdparty passwords without reading them

Tags: security, passwords, password-encryption

I need help with a situation I can't get my head around. I need to store a password from a third-party service, and I dont want it to be human-readable.

I came up with a (possibly dumb) solution: my service generates a secret key that encrypts/decrypts the password, and it uses that key to decrypt the password, when access third-party service is needed, and encrypt it when in need to store it.

**The question**
    is my solution safe? Is it good or bad? Is there a better approach?
   Could you please point directions?

Comment: Don't store passwords. That's the best approach. What is this third-party system and how is this password used?

Comment: Handling 3rd party passwords securely is very difficult and generally requires a separate device to save the password, an [HSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module) or pseudo equivalent. Just encryption it will not work, the attacker will gain admin access to the computer, get the user credentials including encrypted passwords **and** the encryption key—game over. BTW, you will not know you have been attacked. If you bound and determined to do this hire a security expert and pay the cost to make it secure.

Comment: The third-party system is my university's intranet. I'm building and app to access grades, timetables, and so on, since their webpage sucks. The password is used so that I can get a cookie form their webpage. Then I use the cookie to scrape the webpage.
I wanted to be able to push a notification on the student's phone whenever a new grade is out

Comment: @zaph I understand your point, but I'm looking for a DIY thing. This project also helps me understanding about networking.  Not sure if it helps, but about the attaker, but I'm hosting it on Heroku. So, if the hacker gets admin access, its their fault, right?

Comment: "if the hacker gets admin access, its their fault, right?" Not is your fault, you made the choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing retrievable passwords is probably one of the hardest tasks in cryptography. Your application needs to get those passwords plaintext, and the same can do an attacker with enough privileges. There are some common ways to solve this problem though:

1. If the target website offers an authentication service, you can exchange the plaintext password with a token, and store this token (instead of the password) for future requests. The OAuth2 protocol works this way.
2. You can request a master password every time the user starts your application. This master password is used to encrypt the website passwords, but is never stored itself, only kept in memory as long as the application runs.
3. Most operating systems offer some kind of key store, in Windows it is called [Data Protection API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) (DPAPI), in Android it's the [KeyStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html). A key store solves the problem on OS level, that one cannot encrypt a password, without having the master key around (which raises the question of where to store the master key...).

None of the systems above are bullet proof, the application itself has to be able to get the passwords after all. This is why one tries to avoid storing passwords completely (e.g. storing hashes) if possible.

If you can afford dedicated hardware, you could either out-source the password management to a second server which is not accessible from the internet, or you could think about purchasing a [hardware secuity modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module).

Comment: There is an alternative and that is to have a separate server that handles the passwords and is not connected to the Internet, only connected to the server, it is like a HSM without some of the security measures. The server would also have rate limiting capability and alarming for rate excesses. But there best course of action is not to do this at all if proper security can not be provided, find another project.

Comment: @zaph - Thanks for the suggestion, I added it to the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the 2nd option. Would you mind explaining more about this approach?

Comment: @BrunoPastre - You want to encrypt the website passwords before storing them, so you need a master-password to do this. As long as you don't store this master password in your code or in a file, it is much harder to hack the system. So you can request this master password each time, you want to decrypt directly from the user. An attacker won't be able to find it anywhere on the system then.

Comment: @martinstoeckli Thank you! That's the kind of answer I'm looking for!